# RadAutoCompleteTextView autocomplete

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Iam using telerik RadAutoCompleteTextView for populating employees list which is more that 3000 records in sqlite. But whenever am trying to view the page that contains autocomplete, it will take time to load. When i dig deeper about this issue, i found using async will rectify issue. I implemented asyn on next attempt, but the app crashes whenever iam trying to click autocomplete. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: show your some code and crash report

Comment: html [link](https://pastebin.com/CZuwn0kV)
Typescript [link](https://pastebin.com/3i1Q5bn2), am calling initDataItems() in ngOninit

Comment: Are you using the latest version? It might solve your problems

Comment: yeah   version  4.0.0